# How to change JSON data through textboxes and buttons in a ReactJS?

Tags: json, reactjs

I just started learning react.

Please see code in codepen link below.

When you press the edit button, the field in the table is changed to a textbox.

And that's what I want.

I wanna give Click on the edit button again.

How to replace the value of the data in JSON data?

Thanks so much for the help.

```
let UsersData = [
  {Name: 'AAA',Last:"1111"},
  {Name: 'BBBB',Last:"222"},
]

  constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state={
  Editing:false,
}
this.toggleEditing = this.toggleEditing.bind(this)}

toggleEditing() {
    let Editing = !this.state.Editing
    this.setState(
      {Editing: Editing}
    )}
```

FULL CODE IN CODEPEN

[Codepen https://codepen.io/StCrownClown/pen/MEQPzP?editors=0010](https://codepen.io/StCrownClown/pen/MEQPzP?editors=0010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your JSON data first you need to get the user input through your `TextInput` component, to do that you need to define a `value` and an `onChange` props to store the value of the input in your state. Given that your input is a custom component I'll pass those props as props.

Like this:

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {value, onChange, name} = this.props
    return (
      <td>
        <input type="text" 
          value={value} // to display the value
          onChange={onChange} // to store the value on the state
          name={name} // to use use the name as a property of the state
        />
      </td>
    )
  }
}
```

Then in your `TableRow` component state, you need to:

Save those value and handle their changes:

```
this.state = {
    Editing:false,
    // from props to show their current value
    name : this.props.data.Name 
    last: this.props.data.Last
}

// to handle changes
onChange(event){
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name] : event.target.value
    })
  }
```

and pass the above mentioned `props` to the `TextInput`:

```
<TextInput value={this.state.name} name="name" onChange={this.onChange}></TextInput>
<TextInput value={this.state.last} name="last" onChange={this.onChange} ></TextInput>
```

To show those values to the user when to `Editing` is `false` you need to:

Defined a state for your `Table` component so it re-renders with the changes and a function that changes that state when the user is done editing:

```
 this.state = {
      UsersData: UsersData
 }

 saveChanges({key, name, last}){
    // key: unique identifier to change the correct value in the array
    // name: new Name
    // last: new Last
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      UsersData: prevState.UsersData.map(data => {
        if(data.Name === key) return { Name: name, Last: last }
        return data
      })
    }))
  }
```

Finally, pass that function to the `TableRow` component:

```
const rows = [] 
 // now the loop is from the UsersData in the component state to see the changes  
this.state.UsersData.forEach((data) => {
  rows.push (
     <TableRow
        key={data.Name}
        saveChanges={this.saveChanges}
        data={data}
      />
   )
})
```

and call the `saveChanges` function in the `TableRow` component when the Done button is clicked:

```
saveChanges(){
   const {name , last} = this.state
    this.toggleEditing()
    this.props.saveChanges({
       key: this.props.data.Name,
       name,
       last
   }) 
 }


<button onClick={this.saveChanges} >Done</button>
```

You can check the full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/mrrsv2cd/4/).

Comment: It's work!
Thanks a lot.
And if add a delete button to each row, and when click the delete button, it will delete that line.

https://jsfiddle.net/fpLttxpx/1/

Thanks again

Comment: @Thawatchai To delete a row you need to create a delete function that searches for the row to delete and pass it to the `TableRow`. You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/fpLttxpx/2/).

Comment: Nice!. Thank you very much, and how about add new record.
here is my some code https://jsfiddle.net/oyqf4ps3/
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Thawatchai To add a new row you could do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/oyqf4ps3/2/)

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks a lot!.
I'm doing about local storage.
May you help me check it out?
This is the file. > > https://ufile.io/bducz
Thank you very much.